# Datejs and d3.js conflict with transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datejs

I've been using both D3.js and date.js (http://www.datejs.com/) and find out that the transition() method in D3 doesn't work. - that is I can't make any animations with D3 when date.js is also included in the same HTML file.

I suppose it should be scope or namespace conflict, but I don't know how to fix it.
All D3 codes are in one global variable, but it doesn't help.
Anyone have solutions for this, except for not using one of these. :-)?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Strange bug indeed. Just including date.js in the header made the transitions fail. However using moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) did not give any errors.

Comment: I just tried it and I got a tween to run fine with both libraries present. Can you link to a an example showing the problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. I didn't try tween, but transition() failed with NO error messages, just the methods that come after transition() do not work. I'll try momentjs.com. Sorry I don't have files online though.

Comment: I am having the same exact problem with more details here. 
https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/issues/31

Comment: They transitions never execute cause the time comparisons are invalid. d3 expects the time to be in milliseconds long. Date.js causes the time values to be strings.

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, see mbostock's issue's thread. If you need date.js get the one off the trunk as it does not conflict.
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1302